# How can I get header with microprofile.openapi.annotations?

Tags: java, openapi, microprofile

I am using org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations to create rest endpoints. One example is:

```
  @POST
  @Path("/create")
  @Operation(operationId = "createMaintenanceMode",
      summary = "Create a maintenance mode from JSON data request")
  @APIResponses({ @APIResponse(responseCode = "201", description = "created"),
      @APIResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "Bad Request"),
      @APIResponse(responseCode = "404", description = "Requested resource not found"),
      @APIResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "Internal server error") })
  public Response createMaintenanceEntry(

      @RequestBody(name = "data", description = "create request data",
          required = true, content = @Content(mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,
              schema = @Schema(implementation = Request.class)))

      @Valid Request request)
      throws SQLException, IOException, NamingException {}
```

And the Request.class looks like:

```
@Schema(name = CREATE_APPLICATION_REQUEST_NAME, description = CREATE_APPLICATION_REQUEST_DESCRIPTION)
public class Request {

  @NotEmpty
  @Schema(description = CREATE_REQUEST_USER_ID, required = true)
  private String user_id; /* mandatory */
  
  @NotEmpty
  @Schema(description = CREATE_APPLICATION_REQUEST_USER_COMMENT, required = true)
  private String user_comment; /* mandatory */
}
```

I am receiving an authorization token on the header. How can I get its value inside the controller method?